Kafka list topic: TimeoutException
I got Kafka broker with kerberos authentication and trying to list topics getting org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException
> ./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=10.90.5.106:6667 --list 

[2024-05-06 14:53:08,592] WARN [Principal=null]: TGT renewal thread has been interrupted and will exit. (org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin)
[root@odpcp04 bin]# ./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=10.90.5.106:6667 --list
Error while executing topic command : Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1714987458625, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1714987458726) timed out at 1714987458626 after 1 attempt(s)
[2024-05-06 14:54:18,632] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1714987458625, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1714987458726) timed out at 1714987458626 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

What could be the issue ?
